# Introductory Difference Equation - Why is $\Delta \delta y(x) = y(x + \delta)$ as stated in my book?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

The below image is from my book. I am confused how the following is true: $$\mathcal{F}(y(x), \Delta_\delta y(x), \Delta^2_\delta y(x), \cdots; x) = \mathcal{F}(y(x), y(x+\delta), y(x + 2\delta), \cdots; x)$$ This is stated in line $(1.14)$ (bottom right).
[image]

So, how is $\Delta_\delta y(x)$ equivalent to $y(x + \delta)$?

By definition of the difference operator, $\Delta_\delta y(x) = \frac{y(x+\delta) - y(x)}{\delta}$ so...what is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No!  Note the bar on $\bar{\mathcal{F}}$.  You rewrite every appearance of $\Delta_\delta y(x)=\frac{y(x+\delta)-y(x)}{\delta}$, $\Delta_\delta^2 y(x)=\frac{y(x+2\delta)-2y(x+\delta)+y(x)}{\delta^2}$, etc., so an equation of the form
$$
\mathcal{F}(y(x),\Delta_\delta y(x), \Delta_\delta^2 y(x),\dots;x)=0
$$
becomes an equation involving only $x, y(x), y(x+\delta), y(x+2\delta),\dots$ which you denote by
$$
\bar{\mathcal{F}}(y(x), y(x+\delta), y(x+2\delta),\dots;x)=0.
$$

Comment: Oh my gosh, that makes sense. And now this question seems absolutely trivial. Thank you.